# how to make a timer restart?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, label

i have code that reads from a file and streams it through a label. but when i uncheck the checkbox and check it again it just picks up from where it left off

this is my code

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private int start = 0;
    private string lyricspath = @"lyrics.txt";
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(lyricspath);
        string[] read = File.ReadAllLines(lyricspath);
        string join = string.Join(" ", read);
        int number = join.Length;
        start++;
        string str = join.Substring(start, 15);
        if (start == number - 15)
        {
            start = 0;
        }
        label1.Text = str;
    }
```

is there any way to make the timer start completely over each time i uncheck then check the checkbox?

Comment: You should share your instantiation of the timer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reset your start to zero on the check change event, that should reset the timer:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            start = 0;
            label1.Text = string.Empty;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I have a similar process in which I start a timer when a form loads, then if they have a form open for a period of time I give them the option to keep the form open.  If they do, then I reset the timer count to zero and the process starts over.

Comment: Agreed, but you should also reset your label1 text to empty.

Answer (score 1):

set the INTERVAL property... in milliseconds... 1000 = 1 second

Comment: i currently have the interval being set via a trackbar
that isnt the problem the problem is that when if i uncheck the box and check it again it continues to read the file from where it left off i want it to start reading the file from the beginning again

Answer (score 1):

`Timer.Enabled` and `Timer.Start()` are functionally equivalent.

I suspect, you'll need to reset your start variable.

```
if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
{
  start = 0;
  label1.Text = string.Empty;
  timer1.Start();
}
else
{
  timer1.Stop();
}
```

Edit to include the resetting of the label per comment.